# How can make a query string like facebook.com/username?

Tags: asp.net, query-string

I am building a website with asp.net. But I have an issue: I want to make user profile page link like in facebook.

For example,
"hostname.com/username" instead of "hostname.com/profile.aspx?something=something"
How can I achieve this?
Thank you for your time and valuable answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That feature called "URL Routing". If you are using MVC, then MVC Framework has That feature included. But if you are using Web Forms application, then You have to do this manual.

For Web Forms application, You can use Nuget Package **Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls** to  make your application so that it generate url's what you want.

Refer http://www.devcurry.com/2013/05/friendly-urls-in-aspnet-web-forms.html

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx (This is microsoft suggested)

Comment: Yeah I think, this friendlyurl thing is what i am looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is typically done with a framework of some kind, but the concept it fairly simple --

If you're trying to do this quickly, you'll want to do your research on which one to use, but I'll explain the principle that makes it work -

In your server config (like an .htaccess) - you will rewrite the requests for `*.aspx` files go to a central `index.aspx` - this file then bootstraps your index however you want -

In your case, it would take the `/username` portion and query the database for a user with that username, fetch the associated data, and do whatever with it.

It's a relatively simple concept, and you could write something of your own device to bootstrap the request to your code, but you're probably better off looking for some (micro)framework that handles all that for you...

Good luck - !

Comment: Thank you for explaining how it works. I think it is better to search a framework.